# Google Apps Script Returning Wrong Month (subtracting 1)

Tags: google-apps-script

With this simple script in GAS:

```
function testingStuff(){
var date = new Date();
var yr = date.getYear();
var dt = date.getDate();
var mt = date.getMonth();

Logger.log("year: " +yr);
Logger.log("date: " +dt);
Logger.log("month: " +mt);
}
```

I get this as my response:

```
year: 2013
date: 28
month: 2
```

Today is March 28th 2013. 
I have no clue what could be causing this error. Does anybody else get this? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you are not doing anything wrong.  `Date.getMonth()` is 0-based , rather than 1-based. In other words, it returns values in the range 0 to 11 instead of 1 to 12.

Comment: Ahhhh. Of course. That's obnoxious, but at least consistent. OK Thanks!!

Comment: If I am retrieving mail from Gmail based on date will the month act the same way?

Comment: Will `GmailApp.search("after: 2013/1/25")` be looking at January or February?

Comment: It may be obnoxious but it's just the standard JavaScript Date object, not something specific to Apps Script. Gmail uses 1-based months.

Comment: @mat10112 - only .get month() is 0 based.... the other date descriptions / definitions work <normally>, your example will be January.see reference on date objects [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)